# How can I get count of selectable rows?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I set property `isRowSelectable={() => Math.random() > 0.5}`.

This property sets whether you can select this row.

How can I get count of rows which I can select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out how many selectable rows simply by looping over all `RowNode`s and count them:

```
const onGetSelectableRow = () => {
  let selectable = 0;

  gridApi.forEachNode((node, i) => {
    if (node.selectable) selectable++
  });

  alert('selectable rows: ' + selectable);
}
```

### [Live Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/0jzgh0LEWVpzKoVC?preview)